# Some of my functions that I coded months ago, suddently stop working/change behavior ex: load() (baseR)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

it's a weird problem, some of the functions I coded months ago, used everyday since then, somehow seems to randomly stop working. Have you ever had something like that ? I'm pretty new to R and programming in general (last year of masters degree, started coding intensively in R since 9 months).
I get that the most likely answer is that my code is bad, but for example I used a very simple function to import my data:

```
import_tables <- function(){
  filenames <- list.files(
    "../DATA",
    pattern="*.RData", full.names=TRUE)
  for(i in filenames){
    load(i)
  }
}
```

This worked for at least 6 months every day and suddently stopped working last week.
It used to load the object with the name of the file, but now either it does not do anything or it load into an object named `obj` for all file, which is problematic because I get only the last file's object.

Comment: what does your folder structure look like? did you move the files you are loading? can you just run `filenames <- list.files(
    "../DATA",
    pattern="*.RData", full.names=TRUE)` and share that?

Comment: I can't share much more as it's probably confidential, but I didnt moove the files and the `list.files(     "../DATA",     pattern="*.RData", full.names=TRUE)` gets me the correct list of files. I can use load(filenames[1]) and it creates an object called obj

Comment: if it is the correct list of files can you try to load one of them?  like this: `load(filenames[1])` or copy the file path directly into `load`

Comment: Edited my answer with the same idea aha. Also, in ?load, it's not specified that you can change the name of the imported object

Answer (score 1):

First I would take everything out of the function and then replace `for` with `lapply`. The for loop might be causing the issue but can't be certain without testing with your data (which you can't share).

```
  filenames <- list.files(
    "../DATA",
    pattern="*.RData", full.names=TRUE)

  lapply(filenames, load)
```

Comment: Still have a hard time using apply !

Comment: Still I get the same problem that everything is overlapped onto the "obj" object
[[429]]
[1] "obj"

[[430]]
[1] "obj"

[[431]]
[1] "obj"

[[432]]
[1] "obj"

[[433]]
[1] "obj"

Comment: what is the `obj` object? make sure you are using `lapply` and not `apply`

Comment: my other question is how are the .rdata files created? if this worked everyday for months there could have been an issue when creating the rdata files, were they ever overwritten?